# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 RetroFit

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have a basic lorem ipsum response json url as follows: 
https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=all-meat&paras=10&start-with-lorem=10

In my APIService interface I'm calling it as follows:

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface APIService
{
    @GET("application/json")
    Observable<List<NewsFeed>> getProductData();
}
```

My NewsFeed model that uses the response data:

```
public class NewsFeed
{
    private String feed;

    public void setFeed(String feed)
    {
        this.feed = feed;
    }

    public String getFeed()
    {
        return feed;
    }

}
```

Then I'm trying to pass that data from the Url into my recyclerview...

```
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);

    Observable<List<NewsFeed>> observable = apiService.getProductData().subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

    observable.subscribe(new Observer<List<NewsFeed>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(List<NewsFeed> newsFeeds)
        {
            newsFeedList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < newsFeeds.size(); i++)
            {
                NewsFeed newsFeedModel = new NewsFeed();
                newsFeedModel.setFeed(newsFeeds.get(i).getFeed());
                newsFeedList.add(newsFeedModel);
            }
            mAdapter = new NewsAdapter(getActivity(), newsFeedList);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });
}
```

How do I get this error to go away? Is there a specific way to handle string results?

Comment: does your json look like `[{"feed" : "text"},{"feed" : "text"}]` or `["text","text"]` ?

Comment: No, it looks more like [{0: "text", 1: "text"}], if you select the link you can see the exact response

Comment: ?? `["Bacon ipsum dolor amet ..", ","Sausage beef strip steak frankfurter...", ...]` this obviously is not `List<NewsFeed>`... it's more like list of strings

Comment: I'm trying to get those responses, into a list. I was able to do this fine in my AsyncTask

Comment: I just have the NewsFeed model class to pass into the recyclerview, because eventually it will be real data being passed into it... it's more of a placeholder for now

Comment: but json has to fit your model class

Comment: You won't be able to use that placeholder url with the same model. It needs to match

Comment: it does, because the NewsFeed model contains one instance variable for the string responses to go into, instead of the NewsFeed should I just make the List be of type string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need the APIService interface to be like this

```
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface APIService
{
    @GET("/api/?type=all-meat&paras=10&start-with-lorem=10")
    Observable<List<String>> getProductData();
}
```

Then where you are creating your `Retrofit` instance you will write it like this

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://baconipsum.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

After that wherever you are using `NewsFeed` class, replace it with `String`.